# Как отобразить текст android studio

Tags: android

Я хочу что бы при нажатии на кнопку в разделе манифеста менялся текст в android:label=""

Comment: Что вы уже предприняли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем вам это？Вы можете заменить заголовок с помощью

```
setTitle(int titleId)
```

Или

```
setTitle(CharSequence title)
```

Но в манифесте это конечно ничего не изменит.

Answer (score 2):

Это невозможно. Манифест упоковывается в приложение как статический ресурс вместе со строками, иконками, стилями etc. Менять его во время исполнения невозможно.